# How to use Raspberry Pi 4 with an USB to RS232 adapter cable over the serial port

Tags: python, serial, uart

I would like to use a Raspberry Pi4 to control a syringe pump [(see datasheet here and in particular the quick start manual on page1)][1]

The connector cables I used are RJ11 from the Pump to RS232 (from the manufacturer) as well as a standard RS232 to USB converter cable from Benfei ([drivers can be downloaded here][2])

On Windows it worked fine after installing the drivers (was needed). The COM port was recognized and I could test the pump with Arduino.

On my Raspberry I am not getting it to work.

I am this far:
The RS232 adapter is recognized:

> ```
> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
> Bus 001 Device 005: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port / Mobile Action MA-8910P
> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> ```

```
> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | grep "tty" [  960.932258] usb 1-1.3: pl2303
> converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

When using this bare minimum code example:

```
import time
import serial

Serial = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate = 19200, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=1)
#Rate Units
#mL/hr - MH
#µL/hr - UH
#mL/min - MM
#µL/min - UM

def test_syringe(diameter = 10.00, pumping_rate = 10.00, pumping_rate_unit = 'MH', volume_to_dispense = 20.00):
    Serial.write(("DIA " + str(diameter) + "\n").encode())
    message = Serial.read()
    print(message.decode())
    Serial.write("DIA \r".encode())
    message = Serial.read()
    print(message.decode())
    Serial.write("RAT ".encode() + str(pumping_rate).encode() + " ".encode() + pumping_rate_unit.encode())
    Serial.write("VOL ".encode() + str(volume_to_dispense).encode())
    Serial.write("DIR INF".encode())
    Serial.write("RUN \n".encode())


test_syringe()
```

I get at least some feedback from the pump:

```
b'\x02'
0
```

But it is not starting. The linux driver is only available for Redhat. I'm thinking about purchasing another RS232 adapter cable.

Is the code with the carrier return corect?
[1]: https://www.syringepump.com/download/NE-500%20OEM%20Syringe%20Pump%20User%20Manual%20V3.9.pdf
[2]: https://www.think-benfei.com/p_driver.html

Comment: It looks like an off topic question, so I don't write an answer. Try to replace every '\n' (line feed) with '\r' (carriage return)

Comment: Rather than asking convoluted questions why don't you try to systematically debug individual components?

Comment: NOTE RJ11 is a 2 wire telephony interface using a 6P2C connector  - possibly designed for a modem.